# Converting a list of integers to a string

Tags: python

I have a list in the following manner:

```
foo=[21, 38, 38, 56, 23, 19, 11, 15, 19, 13, 20, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10, 11, 0, 11, 8, 12, 5]
```

and I want to convert this into something like:

```
bar=21, 38, 38, 56, 23, 19, 11, 15, 19, 13, 20, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10, 11, 0, 11, 8, 12, 5
```

How should this be done?
I tried `bar=''.join(foo)` but this gives me an error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
''.join(map(str, foo))
```

This maps each integer through `str`, which can then be joined together. Though, you may want to add a comma between them:

```
', '.join(map(str, foo))
```

Comment: Ah, `str` is the string type in python. So it converts a type into a string: `str(5) == '5'`

Answer (score 5):

Or without map,

```
bar = ', '.join(str(i) for i in foo)
```